# Only grep sections of file containing a specific string

Tags: awk

I want to make it easier to find logs for a specific user and I want to only grep/filter the sections which contain the string 15120000000. A section is a line starting with time stamp (Sep 16 19:31:46 in this example. Or it could be everyline starting with "Sep 16"). Is it possible to use grep or awk for this? Thanks in advance for all the help.

Here is the log sample.

```
Sep 16 19:31:46 da1psbc05pev kamailio[31135]: INFO: <script>: onreply_route Rcvd [487] response from[25.11.214.107:5061] MsgId[6384483] From[sip:15120000000@3bc.cloud.comptel.com] callid[f91a7279-15751118-6c5f65af@192.168.1.58]

SIP/2.0 487 Request Terminated
From: "TAC Offnet"<sip:15120000000@3bc.cloud.comptel.com>;tag=B251F2AD-C3A0DEEC
To: <sip:0001@3bc.cloud.comptel.com;user=phone>;tag=dc25d928-0-13c4-6006-cb98c-2310cd2b-cb98c
Call-ID: f91a7279-15751118-6c5f65af@192.168.1.58
CSeq: 1 INVITE
Via: SIP/2.0/TLS 25.11.214.72:5061;alias;rport=54928;branch=z9hG4bKbbd9.62d12aaf57f6574fd99b719735009993.0;i=4e0f7
Via: SIP/2.0/TLS 192.168.1.58:36304;received=199.199.199.122;rport=36304;branch=z9hG4bK47084e2320E46012
Supported: timer,replaces,info
User-Agent: compGear/21.79.9310.0 (compTel 15)
Content-Length: 0

Sep 16 19:31:46 DaHostname kamailio[31135]: : <core> [msg_translator.c:553]: lump_check_opt(): ERROR: lump_check_opt: null send socket
Sep 16 19:31:46 DaHostname kamailio[31135]: : <core> [msg_translator.c:553]: lump_check_opt(): ERROR: lump_check_opt: null send socket
Sep 16 19:31:46 DaHostname kamailio[31135]: INFO: <script>: onsend_route Dumping MsgId[6384483] sending to[199.199.199.122:36304] size[556]  callid[f91a7279-15751118-6c5f65af@192.168.1.58]

SIP/2.0 487 Request Terminated
Record-Route: <sip:25.11.214.72:5061;transport=tls;transport=tls;lr=on>
From: "TAC Offnet"<sip:15120000000@3bc.cloud.Comptel.com>;tag=B251F2AD-C3A0DEEC
To: <sip:0000@3bc.cloud.Comptel.com;user=phone>;tag=dc25d928-0-13c4-6006-cb98c-2310cd2b-cb98c
Call-ID: f91a7279-15751118-6c5f65af@192.168.1.58
CSeq: 1 INVITE
Via: SIP/2.0/TLS 192.168.1.58:36304;received=199.199.199.122;rport=36304;branch=z9hG4bK47084e2320E46012
Supported: timer,replaces,info
User-Agent: CompGear/21.79.9310.0 (CompTel 15)
Content-Length: 0


Sep 16 19:31:46 DaHostname kamailio[31141]: INFO: <script>: onreply_route Rcvd OPTIONS [200] response from[201.125.123.125:46518] MsgId[6331041] From[sip:sips:3] callid[CompTel_1474068706-1077690787]
```

Comment: Show the expected output given that input so we're not guessing.

Comment: May be I wasn't clear enough. This gave me exactly what I wanted.

awk 'BEGIN{RS="Sep 16"; ORS="Sep"} /5120000000/ {print}' /var/log/log

I used date part as of time stamp as record separator (Sep 16) and then selected records based on the number 512000000. So that part is working pretty nice.

Now, is there a way I can make it dynamic? How can I make RS to select any value from Jan to Dec?. Thanks.

Comment: Read [ask] to understand where you're going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming sections are separated with one or more blank lines

```
$ awk -v RS= '/15120000000/' file
```

should do

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the answer. This gave me exactly what I wanted.

awk 'BEGIN{RS="Sep 16"; ORS="Sep"} /5120000000/ {print}' /var/log/log

I used date part as of time stamp as record separator (Sep 16) and then selected records based on the number 512000000. So that part is working pretty nice.

Now, is there a way I can make it dynamic? How can I make RS to select any value from Jan to Dec?. Thanks.